# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax in select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get info only if `o.status_id` is equal to either 4 or 5, but I'm getting this error

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN order_items oi ON i.id = oi.item_id INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id =' at line 14
```

this is my sql statement

```
$sql = '
SELECT 
    i.*, 
    o.*, 
    oi.*,
    u.*, 
    YEAR(o.sold_date) sold_date_Y4,
    MONTH(o.sold_date) sold_date_M4


FROM items i

WHERE o.status_id = 4 AND o.status_id = 5

INNER JOIN order_items oi ON i.id = oi.item_id
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id = oi.order_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = o.user_id
GROUP BY YEAR(o.sold_date), MONTH(o.sold_date), u.name, i.item
ORDER BY YEAR(o.sold_date), MONTH(o.sold_date), u.name, i.item

';
```

From what I can see my MySQL version is 5.7.23

Comment: `JOIN` goes before `WHERE`.

Comment: See docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have used `WHERE` before all your `INNER JOIN`

```
$sql = '
SELECT 
    i.*, 
    o.*, 
    oi.*,
    u.*, 
    YEAR(o.sold_date) sold_date_Y4,
    MONTH(o.sold_date) sold_date_M4


FROM items i

INNER JOIN order_items oi ON i.id = oi.item_id
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id = oi.order_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = o.user_id

WHERE o.status_id = 4 AND o.status_id = 5

GROUP BY YEAR(o.sold_date), MONTH(o.sold_date), u.name, i.item
ORDER BY YEAR(o.sold_date), MONTH(o.sold_date), u.name, i.item

';
```

Comment: Add WHERE conditions after JOIN. If it doesn't work, try without where condition to very all the results is printed on screen.

Comment: Can you run it directly on the server and check for a result? phpMyAdmin or something :)

Comment: @Anand - if I remove the WHERE condition then it works expect for removing anything that isn't related to ostatus_id 4 or 5.

Comment: @zanderwar - it says that it returned an empty result, but there is 4 and 5 for status_id

Comment: I managed to get it. I added a OR condition as well. It looks like I didn't actually have the status_id 5 in my database

Comment: Haha been there, glad you worked it out.. all the best

Comment: WHERE o.status_id = 4 AND o.status_id = 5 it is allways FALSE because status_id cannot be 4 and 5 at the same time. Itr should be **WHERE o.status_id = 4 OR o.status_id = 5**